# Jquery automatic submit - form type file

Tags: jquery, forms

I am searching for a jQuery script that selects a file when the form is automatic submitted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I auto-submit an upload form when a file is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321855/how-do-i-auto-submit-an-upload-form-when-a-file-is-selected)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try .change() event for the input file control. Something like

```
<form action="test.html" id="form1">
    <input type="file" id="fil1" />
</form>

$(function(){
    $("#fil1").change(function(){
        $("#form1").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Works fine in IE8. Didn't check in other versions.