# How do I auto-submit an upload form when a file is selected?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple file upload form. How do I make it submit automatically when a file has been selected? I don't want the user to have to click the Submit button.

Comment: What if the user selects the wrong file? IMO, you should leave it to the user to choose when to submit.

Comment: @Tyler Most people will select the correct file and I am trying to reduce UX friction. For those people who select the wrong file, after it has been uploaded they may choose to delete it.

Comment: "most people" make smart decisions, but most people aren't.

Comment: I agree with @TylerCrompton, users will make the dumbest mistakes and blame you for it, you could add an undo after the submission.

Comment: when the auto-submit is successful via the on change event, how to you then delete the upload lets say the user now decides not to post submit the form

Comment: the best answer is the simplest answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25893747/1536309

Answer (score 227, accepted):

You can simply call your form's `submit` method in the `onchange` event of your file input.

```
document.getElementById("file").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cwvc4/73/

Comment: This works in Safari where as the jQuery solution doesn't seem to work. Strange?

Comment: @henrywright: Yes. In jQuery the `Submit()` call triggers the jQuery `submit` event, but does not fire the underlying form `submit()`. You can of course use `$('form')[0].submit()` to hit the DOM element with jQuery

Answer (score 113):

Just tell the `file`-input to automatically submit the form on any change:

```html
<form action="http://example.com">
    <input type="file" onchange="form.submit()" />
</form>
```

This solution works like this:

- [`onchange`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-onchange) makes the input element execute the following script, whenever the `value` is modified
- [`form`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_form.asp) references the form, that this input element is part of
- [`submit()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) causes the form to send all data to the URL, as specified in `action`

Advantages of this solution:

- Works without `id`s. It makes life easier, if you have **several forms** in one html page.
- **Native** javascript, no jQuery or similar required.
- The code is **inside** the html-tags. If you inspect the html, you will see it's behavior right away.

Answer (score 58):

Using jQuery:

```js
$('#file').change(function() {
  $('#target').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="file" id="file" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: also, the same question was on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704154/jquery-automatic-submit-form-type-file

Comment: Does this approach work in Safari? I'm not sure. I've tested Chrome, IE and FF which all work.

Comment: @ErdalG: Working jQuery version added below. It avoids this problem.

Answer (score 39):

JavaScript with `onchange` event:

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="filename" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit();">
</form>
```

jQuery 
[`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

```js
$('#fileInput').change(function() {
  $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="upload.php" id="myForm">
     <input type="file" id="fileInput">
</form>
```

Comment: add a comment if you do down vote to make clear what's wrong or what should be improved.

Answer (score 12):

The shortest solution is

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="javascript:document.getElementById('form').submit();" />
```

Comment: How about `onchange="this.form.submit()"`

Comment: How about `onchange="form.submit()"`? :)

Answer (score 8):

```
<form id="thisForm" enctype='multipart/form-data'>    
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
</form>

<script>
$(document).on('ready', function(){
  $('#file').on('change', function(){
    $('#thisForm').submit();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is my image upload solution, when user selected the file.

HTML part:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="img_form" method="post">
    <input id="img_input" type="file" name="image" accept="image/*">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('img_input').onchange = function () {
upload();
};
function upload() {
    var upload = document.getElementById('img_input');
    var image = upload.files[0];
    $.ajax({
      url:"/foo/bar/uploadPic",
      type: "POST",
      data: new FormData($('#img_form')[0]),
      contentType:false,
      cache: false,
      processData:false,
      success:function (msg) {}
      });
};
```

Answer (score 5):

If you already using jQuery simple:

```
<input type="file" onChange="$(this).closest('form').submit()"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try bellow code with jquery :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').on('change', "input#MyFile", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#myForm").submit();
    });
});
</script>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <form id="myForm" action="action.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" id="MyFile" value="Upload" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 because this is the only method I found that enabled me to catch the submit event with jquery. The other methods seem to bypass the submit event so I can not do checks on the form or submit with Ajax when using them. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using .NET WebForms a full page submit may not be desired. Instead, use the same `onchange` idea to have javascript click a hidden button (e.g. <asp:Button...) and the hidden button can take of the rest. Make sure you are doing a `display: none;` on the button and not `Visible="false"`.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<form id="xtarget" action="upload.php">
<input type="file" id="xfilename">
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT PURE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("xfilename").onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById("xtarget").submit();
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="http://example.com">
    <input type="file" onchange="Submit()" />
</form>

 <script>
     // it will submit form 0 or you have to select particular form
     document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();       
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put this code to make your code work with just single line of code

```
<input type="file" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit()">
```

This will upload the file on server without clicking on submit button

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#file').change(function() {
  $('#target').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="file" id="file" value="Go" />
</form>
```