# uploading a pic from computer with single button in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image-uploading

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>File Upload Form</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      This form allows you to upload a file to the server.<br />
      <form action="getfile.php" method="post"><br />
         Type (or select) Filename: 
         <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
         <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am working on a php language . I am uploading a pic from my computer . But there are two buttons ie choose file and Upload file . CHOOSE FILE is used to select the picture from PC and upload file button is used as SUBMIT button but i need a single button by clicking on it it will open my pc window to browse the photos and select it and it also act as a submit button . Is there any way to do this with single button

Comment: Where's the PHP, JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: NO there is no such way, period.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky there is no `onChange` event on the `<input type="file">` tag?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky seriously? It IS possible. Easy, to be honest.

Comment: I have seen it in facebook , twitter ..........when click on the add album button and after selecting it will show you the images you have selected

Comment: Can you guys gime a link to a demo? will be a nice learning experience. `CHOOSE FILE is used to select the picture from PC and upload file button is used as SUBMIT button but i need a single button by clicking on it it will open my pc window to browse the photos and select it and it also act as a submit button `

Comment: You can call submit when the input file changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321855/how-do-i-auto-submit-an-upload-form-when-a-file-is-selected

Comment: Note that your form tag is missing the attribute enctype='multipart/form-data', you need it to upload a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to change to things in your form tag:

```
1) Add a name tag: say name="frm"
2) enctype="multipart/form-data"

Then in your input file type add a function onchange="frm.submit();" // Where frm is name of the form
```

Comment: please can you explain me more coz i m new in this field

Comment: Your form tag will look like this: <form name="frm" action="getfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
And Input tag will be: <input type="file" name="uploadFile" onchange="frm.submit();">

Comment: thnx but i need i also don't know about the java script to please can u explain me submit(); also

Comment: frm.submit() will call submit function of you form. frm is name of the form and .submit() will call its submit event i.e. submit button you mentioned in the form.

Answer (score 3):

You can wait an event change on the `input type="file"` and send file after this event.

If you use jQuery, you can send the form with `.submit()`.

Try with something like this

```
$("input[type='file']").on("change", function(){
   $("form").submit();
});
```

`.on("change", handler)` : http://api.jquery.com/change/

`.submit()` : http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0):

used jquery uplodify: [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)

[Demo](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#file_upload_1").uploadify({
        height        : 30,
        swf           : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        uploader      : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
        width         : 120
    });
});
```

also check this for auto upload [auto upload](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/auto/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done in my project:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload File" />
<form action="getfile.php" method="post" id="upload_form" style="display: none;">
    Type (or select) Filename: 
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnUpload').click(function(){
        //Show select file dialog
        $('#uploadFile').click();

        //Wait for user to select a file
        var tmr = setInterval(function(){
            if($('#uploadFile').val() !== "") {
                clearInterval(tmr);
                $('#upload_form').submit();
            }
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: its not working man . when i click on upload , its doing nothing

Comment: i just copy and  pasted your whole code in my page and at top of my page <link href="jquery.js"> , i have written this

Comment: No man. This is my project's code. So, you have to edit all the locators to suit your need. :)

Comment: It works for me only if edited as follows:

   <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile"/>

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code. Just use this as it is and it will work.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Form</title>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type='file']").on("change", function(){
$("#form1").submit();
});
});
</script>
   <body>
  This form allows you to upload a file to the server.<br />
  <form action="getfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1"><br />
     Type (or select) Filename: 
     <input type="file" name="uploadFile" />
     <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```