# uploading and showing an image in php

Tags: image, upload

I'm developing a simple websit, where user can upload and edit their profile
picture. I have implemented it. That is user can browse and upload his new
photo as profile picture. Now at this stage i want to add one more facility.
Whenever the user browses a photo, the new photo should be shown (he then
can upload it if wishes). For example I have the following UI :
[image]

So whenever the user browses a new photo say for example mango.png, the 
new picture(picture of a mango ) should be shown instead of that blank picture.

I do not have any idea how to do that. I seached it in internet but the only think 
i am getting is how to upload any image. So how can do that. Anyone ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to send the image file automatically when the user selects an image in the CommonDialog file browser. For an example code have a look at this question:
[How do I auto-submit an upload form when a file is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321855/how-do-i-auto-submit-an-upload-form-when-a-file-is-selected)

If you want the users to be able to check the image before they decide to make it their profile picture: Let the form upload the file (temporarily) but don't set it as a new profile picture immediately. Finally, if the user sends another form ("Yes, apply new profile picture!"), your script could take the previously uploaded temporary image file and perform the database operations needed to make it the new profile picture.