# Submit a form automatically after file selection when using fileinput.js in Jasny Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I'm using the [fileinput.js](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput) feature in [Jasny Bootstrap](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/)

My aim is to have my form submit automatically after the user has selected a file. I don't want them to have to click on 'submit'.

So far I've tried both [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7321940/1709033) and [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7321919/1709033) solutions. Both soltuions work very well when not using Jasny's fileinput.js but they don't work when I am using it.

```
document.getElementById("file").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
};
```

--

```
$('#file').change(function() {
  $('#form').submit();
});
```

How can I make the form submit automatically after the user has selected a file when using Jasny's fileinput.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Usage section in the docs](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput-usage) and the [source](https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/blob/master/js/fileinput.js), it looks like you need to listen for the custom `change.bs.fileinput` event instead of the native `change` event. Try something like this:

```
$('#file').on('change.bs.fileinput', function () {
    $('#form').submit();
});
```