# JQuery auto upload with input=file form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

I have this form

```
<form id="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>Upload a file:</h3>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" class="fileToUpload"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

And this jQuery code for the submit function (all in the same php file):

```
  $('#uploadFile').submit(function()
  {
    $old=$("#activity").html();

    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(
    { 
      url: "upload.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data)
      {
        $('.info').html(data);   
        $('.info').show();

        $("#content").load("this_same_file.php"); 
      }
    });
  });
```

It works fine. 
What I need to do is to 'automate' the '**submit**' call. I mean, once I clicked OK on the pop-up file window, I would like to submit automatically the form.

I tried to follow the suggestions posted on the thread  [How do I auto-submit an upload form when a file is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321855/how-do-i-auto-submit-an-upload-form-when-a-file-is-selected) but the only thing I can do is a window.alert advertising me that I have clicked the OK button of the pop-up window.

How can I implement this feature in my code ?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger the `submit` action after the `change` event on `input:file` happens,

```
$('#fileToUpload').change(function() {
    $('#submit').click();
    // or $('#uploadFile').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a trigger [(doc)](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#fileToUpload").change(function() {$("#uploadFile").submit();});
```

*Beside I think you have to implement Jquery ajaxForm to send form with file input.*

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#fileToUpload").live( 'change', function () {
 $('#uploadFile').submit();
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated since JQuery 1.7, you should use `.on()` instead.

Comment: @IanKemp thanks you your important information from now i will always use .on()

Answer (score -1):

You can upload the image by calling a `javascript` function on change event or on click event.

```
<input type="file" onchange="uploadSharepic();" id='uploadBtn' value="Upload">
```

And in script

```
function uploadSharepic(){
    var val = $('#uploadBtn').val();
    $('#uploadshareFile').val(val);
    switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()){
        case 'gif': case 'jpg': case 'png': case 'jpeg':
            $( "#uploadShare_image" ).submit();
            break;
        default:
            $('#uploadBtn').val("");
            $('#uploadshareFile').val("");
            $('.sharerror').removeClass('DisplayNone');
            $('.sharerror').addClass('DisplayBlock');
            $('.sharerror').html('Plese select image of type (gif, jpg, png).');
            break;
    }
}
```