# Submitting form with jQuery containing Input of type file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to submit a form using jQuery. The form contains a file upload input which I have disguised using [this SO method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842274/cross-browser-custom-styling-for-file-upload-button/21842275#21842275) and am automatically submitting using [this SO method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321855/how-do-i-auto-submit-an-upload-form-when-a-file-is-selected). When I check the parameters of `_upload` in my controller, `type` has a value but `file` is null.

Where am I going wrong?

View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("_upload", "Config", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form_" + Model.imageType }))
    {
        <label>
            <input id="file_@Model.imageType" type="file" name="file" required />
        </label>
            @Html.Hidden("type",Model.imageType)
    }
....
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#file_@Model.imageType').change(function () {
            $('#form_@Model.imageType').submit();
        })
    })
</script>
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void _upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string imageType) 
    { 
        //dostuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your razor/form to something like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("_upload", "Config", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){}
```