# Auto-submit an upload form when a file is selected, and trigger an action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to submit an uploaded file automatically when the user uploads the file. The shortest way I found was to insert `onChange="form.submit()"`in the upload files `input`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25893747/4861207) I did that, and now when I insert an action to the `submit input` (through JavaScript), it doesn't get triggered.

How can I trigger an event when I do `onChange="form.submit()"`?

#### JSFiddle

Code snippet:

```js
$("form").on('submit',function(){
    alert("It works");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://example.com">
    <input type="file" id="file" onChange="form.submit()" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

**Update**

I know it's possible to perform that with `$('#file').change(function()...` But I want to know if it's possible to do it with `onChange="form.submit()"`.

Comment: Try changing the name of the submit button

Comment: Thanks! I tried tha, and it doesn't work

Comment: insert what action? And yes, you should not name your button submit.

Comment: Do you want the function to run when a file is uploaded AND when the user clicks the submit button, or only in one of those events?

Comment: Only when a file gets uploaded

Comment: @epascarello In the example above, I want to have an `alert` show when a file gets submitted

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: @epascarello Just did that, http://jsfiddle.net/9yg82rxj/1/ and it still doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps give the form an `id`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833032/submit-is-not-a-function-error-in-javascript: "submit is not a function" means that you named your submit button or some other element submit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Solution 1: jsFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/9yg82rxj/3/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(){
        alert("It works");
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="http://example.com">
    <input type="file" id="file" onchange="$('form').submit();" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

[Solution 2: jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/9yg82rxj/4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(){
        alert("It works");
    });
});

function submitForm()
{
    $('form').submit();
}
```

```html
<form action="http://example.com">
    <input type="file" id="file" onchange="submitForm()" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I guess the problem was the missing `$(document).ready();` I should have thought of that.

Comment: This will cause the browser to load the URL contained in the form's action attribute. To avoid this, add an iframe and set the form's target attribute to the iframe's name. You can also employ the iframe's onload event to show your user a loading animation while the upload is taking place.

Answer (score 0):

The `<input>` tag type `file` responds for `change` event when a file is selected by user, so you can do something like this:

```
input.onchange = function (event) {
  // do something
}
```

Checkout the [documentation here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```js
$('#file').on('change', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://example.com">
    <input type="file" id="file" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#file').change(function() {
    alert("Form is being submitted");
    $('#myBeautifulForm').submit();
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myBeautifulForm" action="http://example.com">
    <input type="file" id="file" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```