# Angular force an ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I currently have the following html which consists of 3 buttons (1 hidden). I have a button which triggers a hidden button which is used to select a file to upload and I have a third button which is used to call upload and send the data to the server. I would like to change this so that after selecting a file, the file is automatically uploaded. I am having issues triggering the upload button when a file is selected (and then I will hide the upload button once I have the automatic upload functionality working). I have tried using the onchange event to accomplish this but with no success

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:250px">
        <div class="col-xs-4" align="center" style="padding-left:290px">
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="newProject()">New Project</button>
        </div>
        <form class="col-xs-4" align="center"
            ng-controller="CsvImportController" style="display: inline-block;padding-left:200px" id="csvForm">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-file"
                onclick="document.getElementById('fileBrowser').click(); return false;">Select
                CSV File</a>
            <button id="submitCsv" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="upload()">Upload</button>
        </form>
        <div class="col-xs-4" align="center" style="padding-left:110px">
            <a class="btn btn-default">Browse
                Projects</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="fileBrowser" style="visibility: hidden;"
        class="btn btn-default btn-file" type="file" id="file" file-input="files" onchange="document.getElementById('submitCsv').click(); return false;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571001/file-upload-using-angularjs) for some libraries that will handle all the upload functionality for you as well as provide some other nice features.

`onchange` will not work on `<input type="file"/>` as it will not register a *change* when you select a file. `ng-click` will not work also as it will trigger when the `input` is first clicked, not when a file is selected.

You also can't apply any styles to an `<input type="file" />` either, so I get what you're trying to do here, but `<input type="file" />` does not offer much functionality which is really unfortunate.

You also have 2 ids defined on your hidden input. Make sure there is only one `id` so that you can call it correctly.

Comment: are you sure? I was trying to do something similar to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321855/how-do-i-auto-submit-an-upload-form-when-a-file-is-selected

Comment: Hmm, I tested it in a fiddle and it did not work.  Have you tried putting your `upload()` call into the onchange and what happens?