# Upload image immediately after selected

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, file-upload

My goal is to automatically upload an image to a folder when the file is selected. Following the answer on [how do I auto-submit an upload form when a file is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20951327/5798798), I attempted to use Javascript's `onchange` event to automatically submit the form:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
$ImageName = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$fileElementName = 'photo';
$path = '../images/'; 
$location = $path . $_FILES['photo']['name']; 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $location); 
}
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="photo" onchange="document.getElementById('upload').submit();" id="file" class="inputfile" />
<label for="file">Add Image</label>
<input type="submit" style="display: none;" name="upload" id="upload">
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

When the file is selected, it's not automatically uploaded to a folder.

*Note: I cannot use `onchange="form.submit()"` as I have multiple submit buttons in my form!*

Comment: <input type"submit" style="display: none;" name="upload" id="upload">   ??
why not <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="value" >
You also need to name your inputs in order for PHP to see them

Comment: The submit needs `id="upload"` as I use `document.getElementById('upload')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could simply change it to:

```
document.getElementById('upload').click();
```

Or do something like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById('upload');
button.form.submit();
```

Comment: It seems that updating the code from `.submit();` to `.click();` solved the issue. Many thanks indeed.